# accessing a ForeignKey through the User class (Django)

Tags: python, django, templates, foreign-key-relationship

So i have two classes that are independent of eachother, but both are related to the User (django) class through the use of a ForeignKey. So my question is, how on earth do you go "through" the User object to find something related to User?

Heres an example

```
class A(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(User)

class B(models.Model):
    box = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

now in my view i pulled all of the values for class B

```
B.objects.all()
```

and in my template i was trying to access it like this

```
{% for value in B %}
   {{ value.B.User.item }}
{% endfor %}
```

but that doesn't work.. how can i get access to class A through the user class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I remember right off the top of my head, the foreign keys are traversed automatically when you access them, so it should simply be `value.box.item` assuming `item` is a column in your User table.

As for getting to A from User, I believe [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects) is what you want and the syntax should be something like `some_user.a_set.all()`.  Note `a_set` is really `<model_name>_set` and it will only work if there is a defined foreign key relationship from `some_user` to `<model_name>`.

UPDATE:

You seem to have some misunderstanding about Djangos models.  `some_B_object.box` will be an object of type User.  So, if I have it right above to get to A from B, you should be able to do `value.box.a_set.all()`.

Comment: unfortunately item isn't a column in my user table, thats why im stuck on what to do.. i have 2 classes that are linked through the user table. So B -> USER <- A, so theoretically i should be able to access A from B.. right?

Comment: nope it doesn't.. so i tried value.B.A_set.all and nothing returns

Comment: Did I have a .B. in my samples...?  Also, _lower case_ "A"

Comment: oh sorry i meant that i tried value.box.A_set.all, but ok i went ahead and tried value.box.a_set.all and it successfully returns the objects of class A related to class B, however, when i did value.box.a_set.all.item nothing returns

Comment: why do you keep doing `.item`??? Where did you get that from?  Also, `all` is a function, it needs the `()` after it.  If you just want to get a single A object, try using `get()` rather than `all()`

Comment: oh i think i gave my example a bit messed up, but using get worked. I wasn't using all() or get() because i was using the templating language, however i did just get it to work by doing value.box.a_set.get.car, where car is another hypothetical field of class A. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to do that is to have a related_name in your models such as

```
class Item(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='items')

class Box(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='boxes')
```

Then if you have a user object you could do

```
user.items.all()
```

or

```
user.boxes.all()
```

If an item can only relates to a single box then I would replace the Item.user field with Item.box foreignkey.